# Why option html doesn't work on mobile phones

Tags: html, css, flask

I don’t know why, but I added SELECT MENU using html, everything works fine on the computer version, but when I want to set up SELECT MENU on the phone version, it doesn’t interact with me at all, only if I remove the computer version settings, then the computer version will disappear, but the phone version will be. How to solve this provlem? Here is the link - http://sakhalatin.pythonanywhere.com/

I added classes but didn't work as well, I am doing this site for self developing and I would like to get help from experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On large screens, you are using left:450px; which you should change on the small screen.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 430px){
select {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 23px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: "Noto Sans";
    font-weight: unset;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #242225;
    left: 0;
}
}
```